# Updated pyximport?

Tags: python, cython

I want to use cython with pyximport, as it is for a data mining task whose source code I don't need to distribute, and thus distutils or setuptools would be a pure hindrance.

However, pyximport relies on distutils, it is coded for pyrex, and it is really old. It even fails to setup.

Because pyximport is made of a couple of files, I could tinker with it until it matches my needs. However, I would like to know if there already exists some better pyximport somewhere.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: What's so bad about setuptools? It's useful for building as well distributing software.

Comment: @larsmans Thanks for your comment. Setuptools requires to pay attention to a "building" step, as you yourself noticed.